# Which scripture mention Lord Rama reached Ayodhya on Kaartika Amavasya (Deepawali) after 14 years of exile?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, festivals

[Deepawali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwali) is the one of the main festival of India. It is celebrated because Lord Rama has reached Ayodhya on this day after gaining victory over Ravana (mainly in northern part of India). Deepawali is celebrated on Kaartika Amavasya (darkest new moon night).

This question [What is the significance of the festival Diwali? Why is it celebrated?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-significance-of-the-festival-diwali-why-is-it-celebrated) discuss about the significance of Deepawali. But my question is: Which scripture mention Lord Rama reached Ayodhya on Kaartika Amavasya (Deepawali) after 14 years of exile?

And also, is there any scripture which claims Lord Rama has slayed Ravana on Vijayadashami?

Comment: According to Valmiki Ramayana, Rama returned to Ayodhya in **Chaitra** (April May time) and not In Kartika masa.

Comment: @Surya ok, can you please give reference to this.?

Comment: By the way, South Indians believe Deepavali celebrates Krishna killing Narakasura, and Navaratri and Vijaya Dashami celebrates Durga killing Mahishasura.

Comment: On the day of Diwali, 24th tirthankar Mahavira Swamy attained Nirvana, 16 Gana-kings, 9 Malla and 9 Lichchhavi, of Kasi and Kosal, illuminated their doors. They said: "Since the light of knowledge is gone, we will make light of ordinary matter"

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan OK. But most part of North India celebrates slaying of Naraka one day before Deepawali on Kaartika Krishna Chaturdashi also known as Chhoti (Small/Secondary) Deepawali https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_Chaturdashi. And Vijayadashmai is celebrated for both slaying of Ravana and Mahisasur.

Comment: @Surya Then why do people claim Rama returned in around October-November, if he did return in April-May, that means we are celebrating Diwali for no reason whatsoever!!

Comment: @Chinmay No actually in South India it is celebrated for Krsna's victory over Narakasura. And you have all those other festivals like Lakshmi Puja, Bali pratipada and all.

Comment: @Chinmay You are forgetting Narakasura and the earlier Samudra Mathana. :)

Comment: Diwali is Ashviyuja amavasya not Kartika amavasya. 21 days after Dussehra is still Ashviyuja masa only. Kartika Amavasya is 15 days after Kartika Purnima which is 19 november this month.

Comment: @Sinister There are two systems in hindu calendar as Amanta (Amavasya anta) and Purnimanta (Purnima anta). I follow the later and you follow the former. We count months from Krishna Paksha to Shukla Paksha. So, the difference. You can check both views [here](http://www.drikpanchang.com/vrats/amavasyadates.html) or [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/calendar/indian_regional.html)

Comment: @Surya can you share the verse that mentions the return of Rama in Chaitra moth? I couldn't find the month mentioned its just the panchami tithi when he meets Bharadwaj.

Comment: @Dr. Vineet and @ Triyugi Sorry I didn't notice your messages regarding the Chaitra month (@ Triyugi which is bad since you asked me nearly two years ago). It's not directly mentioned in the Ramayana but it can be calculated from the Kishkindha Kanda where the monkeys say that Sugriva sent us in Ashvayuja month and now Margashirsha has passed and we are into Pausha month. 1/2

Comment: And considering that Sita's deadline was a month from when Hanuman met her you can assume that the war happened in Magha or maximum Phalguna. So Rama would have returned in Phalguna or Chaitra near the time of his birthday.

Comment: The calculations are made in [this chapter](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga53/kishkindha_53_frame.htm)

Comment: Hmmm @Surya it is certainly suggestive of their return in Chaitra but that would mean even Dussehra should be in that month since they did not take long to return from Lanka. I wonder whether this huge difference in Valmiki's Ramayan and current celebrations has anything to do with the precession of equinoxes.

Comment: @Dr. Vineet I think it does have an explanation in that phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

Sri Rama reached Ayodhya in Chaitra month ( March-April), but **not on Kaartika Amavasya**.

1. The vanaras sent in Southern direction in Sarad Ritu (September - October) lost their way and enters in a Big cave and finally reach a big mansion. After coming out of that cave and reaching Ocean, they found that much time was lost and already Vasanta Ritu - Spring season (February - March ) has arrived.

> ते वसंतम् अनुप्राप्तम् प्रतिवेद्य परस्परम् |
>   नष्ट संदेश काल अर्था निपेतुर् धरणी तले || ४-५३-५
>
> "On discussing among themselves they found that spring season has arrived, and they also found the purpose of timely messaging about Seetha to Sugreeva is lost, thus they plumped down onto the surface of earth"
>
> After taking guidance of Sampati, Sri Hanuma flew to Lanka on the same day

---

2. Sri Hanuma spent 1 full night in Lanka and after meeting Sita and fighting with Rakshasas and he came back on the next day.
3. After his coming back and narrating his exploits to Vanaras, immediately they flew back to Kishkinda, with a brief sojourn in Madhuvana., on the same day.
4. Immediately after hearing the news of Sita, Sri Rama started on war expedition on the day when the Nakshtra was Uttara Phalguni .

a) The journey time from kishkinda to Ocean was not provided in Srimad Ramayana.

b) He spent 3 days praying for Ocean god.

> तस्य रामस्य सुप्तस्य कुश आस्तीर्णे मही तले |
>   नियमाद् अप्रमत्तस्य निशास् तिस्रो अतिचक्रमुः || ६-२१-१०
>
> Following the scriptural injunction, that Rama who was devoted to his sacred vow, while sleeping on the ground spread with Kusha grass, spent a time of three nights there."

c) 5 days were spent in construction of Bridge to Lanka.

d) 1 Full day was taken to reach Lanka. Sri Rama spent that night on Mount Suvela.

---

5) On the next day Angada was sent as emissary to Ravana and war began on the same day. On the First (1 day) day of the war , Indrajit bounded Sri Rama and Lakshmana with Nagaastra. However, at the arrival of Garuda, they were relieved.

6) on the 2nd of war Ravana himself enters the battle field, and gets defeated at the hands of and let off by Sri Rama. Kumbakarna was woken up.

7) On the 3rd day of the war Kumbakarna gets killed at the hands of Sri Rama. Indrajit eliminates 67 crores of Vanaras, and Lakshmana gets hurt. Sri Hanuma brings Sanjeevani Hill and Lakshmana gets rejuvenated.

8) On the 4th day of the war , Indrajit gets killed on Krishna Chaturdasi day (It must be Phalguna Month)

> अभ्युत्थानं त्वमद्यैव कृष्णपक्षचतुर्दशीम् || ९२-६-६६
>   कृत्वा निर्याह्यमावास्यां विजयाय बलैर्वृतः |
>
> "Making yourself ready today itself, the fourteenth day of the dark half of this month, you along with the armies, sally forth tomorrow, the moonless day, to victory."

9) The war between Sri Rama and Ravana started on Amavasya day and continued for 1 full day.

---

10) It was described in Srimad Ramayana that Sri Rama reached the hermitage of the sage Bharadwaja, on the fifth (5th) day of lunar month after completion of 14 years of exile.

> पूर्णे चतुर्दशे वर्षे पञ्चम्यां लक्ष्मणाग्रजः |
>   भरद्वाजाश्रमं प्राप्य ववन्दे नियतो मुनिम् || ६-१२४-१
>
> After completion of fourteen years of his exile and on the fifth day of the bright half of the lunar month , Rama, who was disciplined even now, reaching the hermitage of the sage Bharadwaja, offered his salutation to the sage.

Sri Hanuma conveys to Bharata that on the next day, when the nakshtra (Star) was Pushyami , Sri Rama will reach Ayodhya.

> तं गङ्गां पुनरासाद्य वसन्तं मुनिसंनिधौ || ६-१२६-५४
>   अविघ्नं पुष्ययोगेन श्वो रामं द्रष्टुमर्हसि |
>
> "Reaching the coast-line of Ganga-river again, Rama is staying in the presence of the sage, Bharadwaja. Tomorrow, when the moon will be in conjunction with the asteroid, Pushya you will be able to see Rama, without any obstacle."

---

After deciding upon the Crown prince ceremony of Sri Rama, the king Dasaratha directs his priests Vasistha, Vamadeva, etc to make arrangements.

> चैत्रः श्रीमानयं मासः पुण्यः पुष्पितकाननः |
>   यौवराज्याय रामस्य सर्वमेवोपकल्प्यताम् || २-३-४
>   राज्ञस्तूपरते वाक्ये जनघोषो महानभूत् |
>
> "This is the glorious and auspicious month of Chaitra, in which the forests bloom with flowers. Let all arrangements be made for the coronation of Rama as prince." While these words of the king were being completed, there was a great delightful uproar of the people."

The king Dasaratha then informs Sri Rama about the ceremony.

> यतस्त्वया प्रजाश्चेमाः स्वगुणैरनुरञ्जिताः || २-३-४०
>   तस्मात्त्वं पुष्ययोगेन यौवराज्यमवाप्नुहि |
>
> "O, Rama! As you with your good qualities cherished these people, you get the princely kingdom on the day of Pushyami star (when the moon appears in conjunction with the constellation Pushya).."

On the same day, Sri Rama left for the Forest in order to fulful the boon given by his father to Kaikeyi. So it is Chaitra month in which he left Ayodhya.

---

So Sri Rama reached Ayodhya again in Chaitra month only (**March - April**)

Comment: Please avoid trivial edits. Adding bold to old answer without adding much info is not much useful.

Answer (score 2):

Since the war begins against Ravana on the first day of the shraadha period during Dakshinayana, God Rama worships His pitru (forefathers) [Ref: Mahabhagavata Upapurana 40.14-26 translated by PKN Goswami].

Later, on the battlefield, Kumbhakarna kills innumerable vanara and eats many of them. God Brahma appears before God Rama and advises worship of Goddess Durga, though it is an odd time (shraadha) and dark fortnight period [Ref: Mahabhagavata Upapurana 41.13-14, 42.19-23]. God Rama does as told and goes on to kill the mighty Kumbhakarna after a fierce battle [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 6.60-68].

Indrajit was killed 15 days after the war had started, the day before amavasya (no-moon) when the shraadha period ended [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 6.93; Mahabhagavata Upapurana 45.20].

If Ravana is allowed to worship Goddess Durga on the coming poornima (full moon day), he cannot be killed. Therefore, God Rama starts worshipping Goddess Durga from the first day of the bright fortnight in autumn (Ashwina). He fasts during the nights and chants mantra. Devoted worship of Goddess Durga assures the devotee all the desires of the world [Ref: Mahabhagavata Upapurana 36.59-73, 42.13-17, 46.1-33; Devi Bhagavatam 3.30.19, 9.1.144-159].

God Rama had not been able to finish off Ravana after ferociously battling for 7 continuous days and nights [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 6.109].

As per Goddess' instructions, during the seventh to ninth day ceremonies, God Rama's bow is brought before Her [Ref: Mahabhagavata Upapurana 45.27-30].

Finally, on the 10th day of the bright fortnight (in the month of Ashwina), God Rama fires the lethal Brahmastra and kills Ravana [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 6.110]. This day is celebrated even today as Dassehra when the idol of Goddess Durga is immersed in the water [Ref: Mahabhagavata Upapurana 45.34-35]. The preceding days are celebrated as the Navaratri festival, corresponding to God Rama’s worship of the 9 avatara of Goddess Durga (Parvati).

The vanara soldiers return to their respective homes. Vibhishana, God Rama, Sita, Lakshmana, Sugreeva, Angada, Jambavanta, Sushena, Shatabali, Nala, God Hanuman etc. fly back towards Ayodhya in the pushpaka-vimana. En route, they pick up Tara and Ruma from Kishkindha to accompany them towards Ayodhya.

On the fifth day, they stop at Rishi Bharadwaja's ashrama who grants God Rama a boon. He asks that all the out-of-season trees whose leaves had dried up (due to autumn) lined up to Ayodhya should bear fruits and flowers. The wish was granted [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 6.126, 6.129].

The citizens warmly welcome them all back in Ayodhya, with beautiful flowers and lights across the entire city. This day is celebrated as Diwali by Hindus even today. Diwali symbolizes that there is always a victory of good over evil.

Source: ['Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani, excerpts from pgs 43, 45, 49, 50, 52, 53, 57, 58].