# Relation between Laxmi poojan and returning of Lord Rama on the same day

Tags: ramayana, festivals, lakshmi

Is it just a coincidence or is there any relation between Lord Rama returning to Ayodhya from 14 years of exile and the worshipping of Goddess Laxmi on the same day i.e. Diwali

Comment: Many beliefs behind Diwali festival: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-significance-of-the-festival-diwali-why-is-it-celebrated/15628#15628

Comment: Interestingly Ramaji doesn’t return on Diwali as is commonly and unfortunately interpreted. See this question : [Does Rama return in Chaitra or Vaishakha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45549/does-shri-rama-return-in-the-month-of-chaitra-or-vaishakha). Devi Lakshmi is worshipped on Diwali day because she came from the Samudra Manthan on that day (still searching for reference) just as Dhanvantari came on Dhanteras day