# Is Narakasura death is celebrated as Diwali?

Tags: puranas, festivals, narakasura

The day before Diwali is Naraka Chaturdashi, which is believed to be the day when Krishna killed the demon Narakasura. Some believe that Diwali is celebrated to commemorate this event, as it symbolizes the triumph of good over evil.
This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narakasura#:%7E:text=It%20is%20believed%20in%20some,the%20beginning%20day%20of%20Deepavali.) mentions this same belief.

> It is believed in some traditions that before Narakasura's death, he requested a boon from Satyabhama (incarnation of Bhudevi), that everyone should celebrate his death with colourful lights. Thus, this day is celebrated as 'Naraka Chaturdashi' - the beginning day of Deepavali

Is it folklore or are there any references to it in our scriptures? I have already gone through [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/408/what-is-the-significance-of-the-festival-diwali-why-is-it-celebrated). It doesn't even mention about Nara's death as part of the 5 day celebration.

Comment: eh ? that link clearly mentions - *"2. Kali Chaudas: aka Choti Diwali. Demon Narakasura was killed by the lord Krishna."*

Comment: @mar, you are right. The death of Narakasura is celebrated as Kali Chaudas aka Choti Diwali. That's why it is called 'Choti' Diwali. Still, it doesn't answer why Diwali is celebrated.

Answer (score 0):

The boon Naraka asked Krishna was that anyone who takes auspicious bath on the day of his death will not go to hell.

> "Then Kṛṣṇa, having gone near the demon (lying) on the ground, and
> entreated by him, said to the demon: “Choose a boon.” The demon said
> to Kṛṣṇa seated on Garuḍa: “I have nothing to do with a boon, though I
> am Naraka. For the good of other people I am asking for an excellent
> boon. O lord of the lord of all beings, O Madhusūdana, O you who
> remove the fear (of your devotees), those men who take an auspicious
> bath on the day of my death (will) not obtain (i.e. go to) hell.” Lord
> Govinda gave him the boon: “Let it be so.”

Chapter 249, Uttara Kanda, Padma Purana.

Comment: The answer which you have provided is totally irrelevant to the question. I want to know if there any connected between Diwali and Nara's death with scriptural reference

Answer (score 0):

Deepavali is a celebration that illuminates souls to joy. Naraka means the place where souls turn ghosts and demons. When such bad demoniacal attributed invaded Earth, GOD KRISHNA illuminated mother Earth with Swarna  Deepam called Deepavali.

Since Asura can take any form, his form could only be destroyed by GOD KRISHNA.

Asuras can change their forms - biometrics (height weight eyes face nose hairs etc) in addition to invading powers.
They dont have proper identity.